# Some Blogger label pages only showing 4 articles, even though 20 articles have that label

Tags: blogger

I'm looking for help with labels on my blog. I searched here and online for answers but haven't had any luck.

It appears that some of my labels have a limit placed on them, but I can't figure out where that is and how to remove it.

Some Blogger label pages only show 4 articles, even though 20 articles have that label. Other label pages show 12+ articles.

Here's my blog:
https://www.egyptabout.com

Here's a page with only 4 labels, when there are many more posts with that label:
https://www.egyptabout.com/search/label/Pharaohs%20%26%20Queens

Is there some way I can get pages like the one above to show more articles with that label?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that there are around 8 posts in this label. Could you try adding a **jump break** in each of these posts after 1st paragraph itself (Refer to https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/154172?hl=en > *Format a Post* section > *Add a Read More link*)

Comment: Good call! Inserting jump breaks worked. Thanks, Prayag. Please add this again as an answer below instead of making it a reply. That way I can mark it as the working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely happening because of auto-pagination being triggered by the contents of one of the posts. Adding **Jump Breaks** to all the posts in this label would help in this scenario. To add it, go into the post editor and click the [image: jump break icon in toolbar] to add the jump break, Refer to the screenshot below - 
[image: adding jump break to post]

To directly add the jump break into the HTML of the post, insert the following -

```
<!--more-->
```

As for the reason why Auto-pagination happened in the first place, the reasons for the same are varied. Few common reasons are -

1. Directly copying posts from Microsoft Word. This brings lots of unwanted formatting into the HTML of the post
2. The post containing too much content can lead to the HTML size breaching a threshold which triggers auto-pagination
3. Dragging and Dropping images into post leads to problems because rather than uploading to Blogger it sometimes gets saved in Base64 format inside the post HTML